# Setter causing NSZombies (Swift / OBJ-c)

Tags: objective-c, swift, autorelease

I'm running into an autorelease issue with I believe with the line `let searchTerm : String = newValue.uppercaseString`

The code in question is swift code which is being called by obj-c.

When I remove the `uppercaseString` code nothing bad seems to happen with my software, whereas, when its in things go haywire.  Is there something glaring that I'm missing?  Like an `@synchronized` call or something?

[image]

```
///Section 3.5.1.11 - Consist of 8 Characters 0-9 and A-Z and Space - truncates trailing spaces
    var callsign: String {
        get {

            let callsignArray: [UInt8] = [bytes[19], bytes[20], bytes[21], bytes[22], bytes[23], bytes[24], bytes[25], bytes[26]]
            let callsignString = NSString(bytes: callsignArray, length: callsignArray.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let ret =  callsignString! as! String
            return ret.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    }
        set {

            // Make string uppercase
            let searchTerm : String = newValue.uppercaseString

            // Scan for invalid characters
            let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[^A-Z0-9 ].*", options: nil, error: nil)!
            if regex.firstMatchInString(searchTerm, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(searchTerm))) != nil {
                NSException(name:"name", reason:"Invalid character past into Callsign", userInfo:nil).raise()
            } else {
                println("No special characters")
            }

            var acid: String = searchTerm;

            // Truncate to length


            while (count(acid) < 8) {
                acid = acid + [" "]
            }

            // Assign only 8 characters to string
            let buf = [UInt8](acid.utf8)
            for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
                    bytes[19 + i] = buf[i]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using. Xcode 6.3 beta 2 fixes some issues with regard to uppercaseString (see the release notes).

Comment: Version 6.3 (6D520o) (might be 6.3 beta1)

Comment: Xcode 6.3b2 has build ID 6D532l.